# HTML & CSS Auto height not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a carousel with images/descriptions in it and my height:auto does not work properly. Height computed is too big

JSBin:   **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ximut/1/edit)**

I can only guess that this is because my .shadow class which is relative with height 150px.

Please take a look on it.

Edit: code as requested

This is result of one item from carousel

```
<div class="carousel2">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl-example" style=
        "opacity: 1; display: block;">
            <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
                <div class="owl-wrapper" style=
                "width: 4092px; left: 0px; display: block; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease; transition: all 200ms ease;">
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 341px;">
                        <div class="pc">
                            <div class="c">
                                <img alt="image" src=
                                "http://www.ramp-alberta.org/_system/ThumbnailCache/UserFilesImageAug~16~Site~1_004jpg.300.-1.-1108757834.jpg">

                                <div class="shadow">
                                    <div class="description">
                                        Event1
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my css

```
.carousel2
{
    overflow: hidden;
    /* height:400px; */
    background-color: #344754;
}

.carousel
{
    width: 1364px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
}

.shadow
{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 150px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(222,103,21,0.7);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#B2344855', endColorstr='#B2344855');
    height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.pc{
    /* border: blue 1px solid; */
    width: 1%;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.c
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.description
{
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: "FSRufus";
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

.owl-item
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Put your code in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

You should give class carousel2 a min-height so that CSS will know till what it needs to scale image. Try to use exact size images to save processing time. Also remove height from class Shadow. This should help.

Comment: your answer does not work. Removing height from shadow class removes my transparent bacground.